# koa: mongodb/redis active connection count ever-increasing

Tags: node.js, mongodb, redis, koa, io.js

I am using a middleware to pass my mongodb/redis client instance around like this:

```
function *middleware(next) {
    // allow downstream to handle db connection error gracefully
    try {
        this.db = yield mongodb.apply(this);
    } catch(err) {
        this.db = false;
        this.app.emit('error', err, this);
    }

    try {
        this.redis = yield redis.apply(this);
    } catch(err) {
        this.redis = false;
        this.app.emit('error', err, this);
    }

    yield next;
};
```

yield mongodb.apply(this), call something like.

```
// build server string
var url = 'mongodb://';

if (opts.user && opts.pass) {
    url += opts.user + ':' + opts.pass + '@';
}

// basic connection url
url += opts.server + ':' + opts.port
    + '/' + opts.database + '?w=' + opts.w;

if (opts.replSet) {
    url += '&replicaSet=' + opts.replSet;
}

if (opts.userdb) {
    url += '&authSource=' + opts.userdb;
}

// make sure we have active connection to mongodb
return yield mongo(url);
```

yield redis.apply(this), call something like.

```
var client = redis.createClient(opts);

// prevent redis error from crashing our app
client.on('error', function(err) {
    // you can log driver connection attempts here
});

// make sure we have active connection to redis
yield client.select(opts.database);

return client;
```

But with this pattern I am seeing ever-increasing active connections to mongodb/redis, which eventually reach a limit and prevent drivers from open more connections.

```
// for redis

# Clients
connected_clients:64
client_longest_output_list:0
client_biggest_input_buf:0
blocked_clients:0

// for mongodb

"globalLock" : {
    "totalTime" : NumberLong("858671365000"),
    "currentQueue" : {
        "total" : 0,
        "readers" : 0,
        "writers" : 0
    },
    "activeClients" : {
        "total" : 329,
        "readers" : 0,
        "writers" : 0
    }
},
```

My best guess is I am not re-using client properly. Can someone give me a simple example on how to reuse a redis client/mongodb client properly in koa context?

Preferably I would like to retain the ability to catch connection error like above, so my node.js app doesn't go down just because my database is down.

PS: I mainly use `yieldb` and `then-redis` due to their promise-base api, but an example using native drivers are fine too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out the problem is pretty obvious.

Instead of this:

```
function *database() {
    var client = yield mongo(this.mongo.url);

    return client;
};
```

I should be doing this;

```
var client;

function *database() {
    if (client) {
        return client;
    }

    client = yield mongo(this.mongo.url);

    return client;
};
```

Which cached the instance instead of creating more instances (which in turn opens more connections).